# Sencha Touch 2 - togglefield alignment to the right inside a fieldset component

Tags: sencha-touch, alignment, sencha-touch-2, toggle, fieldset

does anyone know how to align a `togglefield` in Sencha Touch 2 to the right side of the `fieldset` component? Having this simple example:

```
Ext.widget("fieldset", {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'togglefield',
            label: 'Toggle 1',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'togglefield',
            label: 'Toggle 2'
        }
    ]
});
```

The ouput looks fine except of the fact the the two togglefields are aligned to the left side just next to the label text. I would like to have them aligned to the right side of the `fieldset` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Ext.widget("fieldset", {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'togglefield',
            cls:'rightAligned',
            label: 'Toggle 1',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'togglefield',
            label: 'Toggle 2'
        }
    ]
});
```

And add a style like

```
.rightAligned .x-toggle {
    float:right;
    margin-right:1em;
}
```